# MySQL exception on Ubuntu : com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am unable to connect mysql db from below mentioned example.

> class JDBCTest {
>
> ```
> private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost";
>
> private static final String user = "root";
>
> private static final String password = "abc";
>
> public static void main(String args[]) {
>     try {
>         Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
>         System.out.println("Success");
>
>     } catch (Exception e) {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     }
> } }
> ```

The stacktrace is as follows

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException:
Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is 
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure 
property file provide to spring contains: jdbcDriverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mynumber jdbcUsername=root jdbcPassword=rock
```

Comment: The stack trace will include the cause. Can you provide it?

Comment: im getting the below error actually :(
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

property file provide to spring contains:
jdbcDriverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mynumber
jdbcUsername=root
jdbcPassword=rock

Comment: @just_java Consider adding that as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Is your mysql-connector jar file on your classpath? Also, how do you load your MySQL JDBC driver. It should be like the following:

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    System.out.println("Success");

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: i am using ubuntu and already set the class path on ubuntu..